# insert into table where not exists (dbt)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, snowflake-schema, dbt

I want to insert new data into the `STG.NEW_TABLE` when the `id` does not already exist in that table.

Since we can't use insert statements in dbt, I am not sure how to convert this query for dbt:

```
insert into STG.NEW_TABLE
select FILE_NAME::string                  as file_name,
       id::string                         as id, 
       XMLGET(f.value,'value'):"$"::string  as val
from STG.OLD_TABLE ot,
lateral flatten(input => XMLGET( ot.XML_DATA, 'data' ):"$") f
where not exists (select id 
                  from stg.NEW_TABLE nt
                  where nt.id=ot.id);
```

I tried breaking it into two parts where I first flatten the xml into a TMP view and then do a union in another model:

```
(SELECT * FROM {{ref('TMP_VIEW')}} where id NOT IN
    (SELECT id 
     FROM STG.STG.NEW_TABLE))

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM STG.NEW_TABLE
```

as suggested here: https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/migration/tools/migrating-from-stored-procedures/2-inserts

While it seems to work, it doesn't feel like the most efficient solution. I do not want to split the process into two parts. I am gussing something with CTEs might be better. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

In dbt you can set the materialization of a table to be incremental in the `schema.yml` file or within the sql file itself with:

`{{ config(materialized='incremental', dist='id') }}`
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/materializations#incremental

This will only insert records that don't already exist within the table

##### edit based on comments

What you can do is union the new and old table, then rank the id to retrieve a unique one. This allows the model to be incremental, and by specifying which data comes from the old/new table you can ensure only new records are inserted.

```
{{ config(materialized='incremental', dist='id') }}

with cte as ( 
    select *, 0 oldtable from stg.NEW_TABLE
    
    union 
    
    select FILE_NAME::string                  as file_name,
           id::string                         as id, 
           XMLGET(f.value,'value'):"$"::string  as val,
           1 oldtable
    from STG.OLD_TABLE ot,
    lateral flatten(input => XMLGET( ot.XML_DATA, 'data' ):"$") f
    where not exists (select id 
                      from stg.NEW_TABLE nt
                      where nt.id=ot.id)
    
)

final as ( 
    select *, 
        row_number() OVER ( order by oldtable, id ) rn
    from cte 
)

select
    file_name,
    id,
    val
from final
where rn = 1
and oldtable = 1
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but my question was about how to modify the query for dbt. I cannot use inserts

Comment: and what if we do not have unique keys?

Comment: Surely `id` is unique in `stg.NEW_TABLE` because you'll only insert records that don't already have that given id? Unless `OLD_TABLE` contains duplicate ids on the first run?
And your first query should work if the materialisation is set to incremental and you remove the insert statement so its just a select

Comment: yup, the OLD_TABLE is likely to have duplicates and at the end, I only want to keep the first or (1) occurence

Comment: Ah okay, I've updated the answer with a potential solution